# Analyzing roster set notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For each  ∈ ℤ⩾0, let  = { ∈ ℤ⩾0 ∶  =  for some  ∈ ℤ⩾0}.

D1 = {1}

D2={1,2}

D3={1,3}

D4={1,2,4}

D5={1,5}

Find the following:(write in roster notation)

1.{ ∈ ℤ⩾0 ∶  ∈  for some  ∈ ℤ⩾0}

2. { ∈ ℤ⩾0 ∶  ∈  for all  ∈ ℤ⩾0}.

My attempt:

1.{1,2,3,4.....}

2.{1}

Is my attempt for question 1 correct? I could not think of a more convincing answer and if my answer happens to be correct, can anyone else explain how to derive the answer for both part 1 and 2. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are both correct. My preference for convincing myself that they are correct is to rewrite the definition of $D_k$ in English: it's the set of all positive integers $n$ that are factors of $k$.

Since every integer is a factor of itself, every positive integer is in some $D_k$, so you have answered (1) correctly.

Since only $1$ is a factor of every integer, your (2) is right too.

**Edit** after a careful reading. The question specifies nonnegative integers, not positive integers. Then in fact $D_0$ contains all nonnegative integers, since you can always write $0 = 0 \times n$. The answer to (1) should include $0$ too. The answer to (2) is still correct as is.

Comment: thanks for the tips!